# Mostrar elementos de ArrayList en otra ventana

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación que realiza un sorteo entre varios participantes y muestra el resultado en un JDialog. Tengo dos errores en el código que no la permiten ejecutar bien:

```
    private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    //  Convierte el arreglo textoConNombres a una lista listaNombres
    String[] textoConNombres = jTextArea1.getText().split("\n");
    List<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<>
    (Arrays.asList(textoConNombres));

    Random sorteo = new Random();

    //  Obtiene el valor del comboBox

    //No puedo castear de object a int en la parte de JComboBox1
    int cantTitulares = Integer.parseInt(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    ArrayList ganadorTitular = new ArrayList();

    /*  Hace el sorteo las veces que dice el comboBox
        agrega al ganador a un arrayList aparte
        lo elimina de la lista para hacer el sorteo con el resto
        de los participantes que quedan sin ganar.*/

    for (int i = 0; i < cantTitulares; i++) {
        int ganador = sorteo.nextInt(listaNombres.size());
        ganadorTitular.add(ganador);
        listaNombres.remove(ganador);
    }



    // Muestra el resultado en VentanaGanador, que es otra clase

    VentanaGanador ventGanador = new VentanaGanador();
    for (int i = 0; i < ganadorTitular.size(); i++) {

        // Aquí no puedo seleccionar el índice del array para mostrar el elemento
        ventGanador.etiquetaGanador.setText(/////);

    }
```

La idea básicamente es que dentro del `for` se realice el random y se vaya quitando la persona que ganó para que no vuelva a salir sorteada. El problema es que no puedo mostrar los objetos del Array, intenté y busqué pero no sé cómo.

Comment: Saludos, Martín. ¿De qué manera deberías seleccionar el índice del array para mostrar el elemento? Eso que colocaste en `ventGanador.etiquetaGanador.setText(/////);`

Comment: Eso es justamente lo que no puedo entender, no sé qué método puedo utilizar para mostrarlo en pantalla

Comment: Por casualidad, ¿la forma en que quieres hacerlo te muestra un error similar a `Object cannot be converted to String`?

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿qué es lo que quieres mostrar en esa nueva ventana? ¿El número del ganador, o el nombre del ganador?

Comment: @C.Rodriguez Exactamente ese es el error que me muestra. Quisiera mostrar el nombre de o los ganadores, no su número.

Comment: Avísame si te sirve la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos, Martín.

Verás, la forma en que se convierte (o 'castea') un `Object` es diferente a como se realiza usualmente con `String`, en tu código estás utilizando la segunda forma:

`Integer.parseInt(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());`

Si te das cuenta, esto: `jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()` retorna un valor de tipo `Object`, entonces tienes dos opciones, o haces que todo el modelo del `JComboBox` sean siempre valores enteros (puesto que para eso se utilizarán), o bien, simplemente conviertes el `Object` retornado a entero.

Para no entrar en muchos detalles, puedes utilizar la segunda forma. Para lograrlo debes hacer algo como esto:

`int cantTitulares = (int) ((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());`

De esa manera, obtendrás el `Object` del `JComboBox` como un entero.

Por otro lado, tienes el problema de mostrar en una etiqueta (supongo que te refieres a un `JLabel`) el o los ganadores generados. Si lo que deseas es mostrar el **nombre** del ganador (los que agregaste en la lista `listaNombres`)  primero debes hacer una modificación en el `for` donde eliges a los ganadores, ¿por qué?. Bueno, si revisamos tu código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cantTitulares; i++) {
    int ganador = sorteo.nextInt(listaNombres.size());
    ganadorTitular.add(ganador); // Aquí estás guardando un entero
    listaNombres.remove(ganador);
}
```

`ganador`es un **entero**, para que guarde el nombre del ganador sería:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cantTitulares; i++) {
    int ganador = sorteo.nextInt(listaNombres.size());
    ganadorTitular.add(listaNombres.get(ganador));  // Obtienes el nombre de la lista según el entero elegido
    listaNombres.remove(ganador);
}
```

De esa manera, al momento de mostrarlos en la `etiquetaGanador`, harías esto:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ganadorTitular.size(); i++) {
    ventGanador.etiquetaGanador.setText((String) ganadorTitular.get(i));
}
```

`(String) ganadorTitular.get(i)` lo que hace es convertir el `Object` en `String` para que pueda ser agregado al `JLabel` como texto. Esto se debe a que en el `ArrayList` no indicaste el tipo de dato y por defecto los almacena como `Object`.

EDIT:

Con respecto a tu pregunta en el comentario sobre agregar los demás nombres, una forma realmente sencilla y que te permite mantener todo justo como lo tienes, es utilizando código `HTML` dentro del texto que le pondrás al `JLabel etiquetaGanador`.

Además, para esto deberías antes realizar una pequeña modificación en el `for` que utilizas para poner el nombre de los ganadores en ese `JLabel`.

Tendría que quedarte algo así:

```
String ganadoresStr = "<html>"; // Se crea la cadena de texto con la etiqueta inicial <html>
for (int i = 0; i < ganadorTitular.size(); i++) {
    ganadoresStr += ganadorTitular.get(i); // agrega el primer ganador
    if (i + 1 < ganadorTitular.size()) { // verifica si existirán más ganadores
        ganadoresStr += "<br>"; // si existirán más, agrega salto de línea para agregar al otro debajo de él
    }
}
ganadoresStr += "</html>"; // finaliza la etiqueta
ventanaGanador.etiquetaGanador.setText(ganadoresStr); // ajusta el JLabel con todos los ganadores
```

Básicamente lo que hace es añadir el nombre de los ganadores en una misma cadena de texto, y cada ganador, lo separa con la etiqueta HTML `<br>` (lo cuál corresponde a un salto de línea). El `if` dentro del `for`, solamente verifica si debe o no agregar esa etiqueta (es para evitar agregar un salto de línea al final). Y por último cierras la etiqueta HTML con `</html>`.

De esta manera, los nombres de los ganadores quedarían como una 'lista' en el mismo `JLabel` sin necesidad de modificar tus componentes.

Comment: Pensé que iba a funcionar todo genial porque entendí tu explicación (que es genial), pero al ejecutar y hacer click en el botón de sorteo me sale este error: 
        Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
        java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to 
        java.lang.Integer'

@CRodriguez

Comment: ¿En qué parte del código te salta el error? Sospecho que debería ser en el primer error que dijiste, porque es el único `Object` convertido a `Integer`

Comment: Genial! No tira más el error, pero ahora no realiza el sorteo, voy a ver dónde está el problema. Me parece raro. No abre `VentanaGanador`

Comment: Listo, actualicé la respuesta con la forma en que te sirvió.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Asegúrate de mostrar la ventana con `ventanaGanador.setVisible(true);`.

Comment: Si, me acabo de dar cuenta jaja. Muchas gracias. Tienes idea de cómo podría mostrar los ganadores en un jpanel y no en un label? Porque al mostrar más de uno no lo hace, solo trabaja en una línea.

Comment: Podrías utilizar el mismo `JLabel`, pero agregando algunos comandos `HTML` en el texto, así podrías crear varias líneas en un mismo texto.

Comment: Saludos nuevamente, @Martín, revisa el `EDIT` de la respuesta, ahí añadí como debería lucir de una forma sencilla, tal vez no la adecuada, pero te ahorra tiempo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y la claridad para explicar, me sirvió muchísimo.

Comment: Con gusto, @Martín. Me alegra que te haya servido. :-)

Comment: ¿Hay manera de contactarte por privado? Soy nuevo acá y no sé si se puede

Comment: Como mensajería instantánea creo que no es posible. Pero revisa mi perfil, ahí encuentras mi correo personal.

Comment: Te lo pregunto por acá y si es complejo lo podemos charlar por correo: 
Tengo que pegar los nombres de los participantes copiándolos de los "Me gusta" de una plublicación. Obviamente se copian con texto que no quiero que esté, como por ejemplo el "Agregar a amigos" ¿Existe la posibilidad de que cuando copio todo ese texto y apreto en un botón se pase al JList ya sin ese texto no deseado? No sé cómo borrarlo, probé varias cosas pero no funcionaron.

Comment: Sí que se puede @Martín, pero creo que será algo complicado responderlo por comentarios, envíame un correo.

Comment: Ya te envié un correo :)